# Android JavaScript interface, unexpected alert

Tags: javascript, android, alert

I created javascript interface class with method String sayHello() that returns "Hello".
When I want to use that function in javascript (for example console.log(sayHello());), android displays alert with "Hello" inside. I didn't use alert method in javascript so why that alert appears and is there any way to define sayHello() function in java that not display alert.

Edit: When I remove WebChromeClient from my WebView, alert don't appear but then regular javascript alerts (alert(sayHello());) stops working too.

Comment: Is this not the default "Hello" that is added to a newly created Activity? Just making sure.

Comment: No, it is not. I think that you don't understand my question.

Comment: Can you post your code?